# Laravel Validation is validating data but then redirecting to the same page with the inputs without executing the following code

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.5

Here is my code for validation.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'phone' => 'required|unique:users',  
        'user_name' => 'required|unique:users',
        'operator_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'operator_nid' => 'required|numeric|unique:operators',
        'operator_password' => 'required',
        'operator_gender' => 'required',
        'operator_birthday' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('operator/create')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
    }

    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->operator_name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->phone = $request->phone;
    $user->user_name = $request->user_name;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->type = 3;
    $user->save();

    $operator = new Operator;

    $operator->operator_name = $request->operator_name;
    $operator->operator_email = $request->email;
    $operator->operator_phone = $request->phone;
    $operator->operator_nid = $request->operator_nid;
    $operator->operator_user_name = $request->user_name;
    $operator->user_id = $user->id;
    $operator->type = 3;
    $operator->operator_gender = $request->operator_gender;
    $operator->operator_birthday = $request->operator_birthday;
    $operator->operator_occupation = $request->operator_occupation;
    $operator->operator_facebook = $request->operator_facebook;
    $operator->operator_twitter = $request->operator_twitter;
    $operator->operator_gplus = $request->operator_gplus;
    $operator->operator_address = $request->operator_address;

    if ($request->hasfile('operator_pro_pic')){  
        $image = $request->file('operator_pro_pic');
        $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/operator/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(950, 700)->save($location);
        $operator->operator_pro_pic = $filename;               
    }
    $operator->save();

    return $user;
}
```

I am trying to create an operator and a user at the same time. email, phone and user_name should be unique in the user's table and other data will be validate from the operators table. Validation is working as it is giving me the errors but after validating it's not going further. So my code after the validation is not executing. What is the possible reason for this?

Comment: show your code after validation part

Comment: OK, i am giving the full part of the controller method by editing the question.

Comment: try `dd("ï am validated")` before `$user = new User;` and show us

Comment: it's not working. as i said anything after the validation logic is not executing

Comment: what happen if you `dd("inside validator")` inside validator fails block??

Comment: if ($validator->fails()) {
            dd('its ok');
            return redirect('operator/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
        }
it's giving its ok message.

Comment: Seems your input are having validation errors. You should change your validation rules according to your form input.

Comment: well, its not giving me any validation error if all the inputs are ok. if a duplicate entry or a field is blank it's giving me the errors.

Comment: as your  validation rules i guess.

Comment: My bad! the problem was because of the password field name not matching in validation. My Apology

Comment: glad at least you have solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validator);
    }
```

The better way will be to create a request file by using

```
php artisan make:request requestName
```

define all the validation in there. In this case if your validation fails the application will return back with error and old-inputs without reaching to the controller.

Comment: the code block you are suggesting and the one i used will do all the same. so in the validation there's nothing wrong. the problem is  the part of the code after validation is not executing.

Comment: Have you tried using dd($request->all()) after validator check. May be your request not passing the if condition. Nothing else seems to be wrong.

Comment: My bad! the problem was because of the password field name not matching in validation. My Apology

Comment: I will still suggest you to use laravel request for validation. It reduces complexity in out controller.

Comment: I know. I have used before :)